# twitter API: query tweets with conversation id

Tags: api, twitter, twitterapi-python

I was using the following code in the terminal to search for all the tweets in the given conversation:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=conversation_id:107679773517545473&tweet.fields=in_reply_to_user_id,author_id,created_at,conversation_id' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer $bearertoken'
```

But I got the following result(I also tried conversation id from twitter's example 1279940000004973111 with the same result)

```
{"meta":{"result_count":0}
```

I don't know why.Is that because I don't have an academic license?

Comment: How old are the Tweets in that conversation? The recent search API is 7 days of history.

Comment: It is really old tweets. So is there any way to get old conversation?

Answer (score 0):

`/recent` only gives you tweets that are less than 1 week old. That means, even if you have multiple tweets with same conversation id, you only get tweets that are less than 1 week old. That is why you are getting `{"meta":{"result_count":0}`.  Probably you will need to have academic access. Haven't found any other ways to get old tweets on Internet.